# ListView.builder widget not scrolling

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a ListView.builder widget on my page. The problem is the widget is not scrolling when it display its results. Please what am i doing wrong?. The following code show what i have tried so far.

I have tried putting only the ListView.builder Widget on a page, the widget scrolls in that case, but once i add another widget the Listview stop scrollng.

@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(

```
          title: Text(widget.title,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          child:Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child:Expanded(
                      child: Image.asset("assets/images/1frenchToast.webp"),
                    ),
                    // ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  //scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount:  foodCategory != null?foodCategory.length:1,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    return ListTile(
                      //dense: true,
                      leading: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                        child:Image.asset('assets/images/3poached-egg.webp',),
                      ),
                      title: Text(foodCategory != null?foodCategory[index].foodType:1),
                      onTap: (){
                        _navigate(dropDownSelectedItemState, foodCategory[index].foodType);
                      },
                    );
                  },shrinkWrap: true,
                  // physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),

                ),
              ),

            ],
          ),

        ),

        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: null,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
```

I want to be able to make my ListView.builder scrolls using the code displayed

Comment: why are you using so many `SingleChildScrollView` ? Just use a column as you main `body` widget, and wrap the `ListView.builder` with a `Expanded`

Comment: I think I answered this in the comment of your previous question

Comment: @VidorVistrom Yes your replies has completely solved the problems, I didnt see the reply on time,it was why i created this thread again. Thanks again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the suggestions of @VidorVistrom in another thread, this is how i solved the problem. I wrapped the ListView.builder inside a container widget and simply gave it a height of 200 and removed the SingleChildScrollView around the ListView.builder, and boom  that solved the problem. In case this help other people.

The complete code is as shown below:

```
@override Widget build(BuildContext context) { return Scaffold( appBar: AppBar( title: Text(widget.title,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          child:Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child:Expanded(
                      child: Image.asset("assets/images/1frenchToast.webp"),
                    ),
                    // ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(//child:SingleChildScrollView(
                                  height: 200,
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                                  //scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                  // physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                  child: ListView.builder(
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                    physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                    itemCount:  foodCategory != null?foodCategory.length:1,
                                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
                                      return ListTile(
                                        dense: true,
                                        leading: Container(
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                                          child:Image.asset('assets/images/3poached-egg.webp',),
                                        ),
                                        title: Text(foodCategory != null?foodCategory[index].foodType:1),
                                        onTap: (){
                                          _navigate(dropDownSelectedItemState, foodCategory[index].foodType);
                                        },
                                      );
                                    },shrinkWrap: true,
                                    // physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),

                                  ),//)

                                ),

            ],
          ),

        ),

        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: null,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
```